# Getting FileNotFoundException for a file that is proven to exist by WatchEvent

Tags: java, filereader, filenotfoundexception, watchservice

I'm writing a program that watches a certain directory for any new files, and whenever new files arrive, the program takes some action on those files. I'm using WatchService to watch the directory, so I feel like it can be conclusively proven that the file does indeed exist.

However, whenever I attempt to create a FileReader on the file that was found by my WatchService, I get a FileNotFoundException.

I am making sure that Java is using the Absolute Path when attempting to create the FileReader, so I have no reason to believe its looking in the wrong place.

I've done lots of research on FileReader, FileNotFoundException, and both the File and Path objects, yet I'm still unable to determine why this exception is being thrown.

I'm not too familiar with WatchService, but I used code that I have found on other forums and it seems to be detecting the file just fine and passing it through. Code is below.

```
try
{
  WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
  Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\sample\\path")
  WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);  
  for(;;) 
  {
    try
    {
      key = watcher.take();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException exception)
    {
      //code
    }
    finally
    {
      for(WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents())
      {
        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

        if (kind == OVERFLOW)
        {
          continue;
        }

        WatchEvent<Path> trigger = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
        Path filename = trigger.context();
        filename = filename.toAbsolutePath();
        File theFile = filename.toFile();
        //EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(theFile);
        /**
        *  more code
        **/
      }
    }
  }
}
catch(IOException exception)
{
  //code
}
```

As stated in the code block, a java.io.FileNotFoundException is thrown after I try to create a FileReader based on the file. I know that the file exists because my WatchService detected the file being created and provided the file's path with trigger.context().

I even made sure that FileReader is using the absolute path of the file by calling toAbsolutePath() on the file.

I have a debug statement right before the problematic line of code that prints the path of the file in question, and yes, the path that is printed is the correct absolute path of the file. So why does FileReader not detect the file?

I hope somebody can help me, I realize this post is exceptionally long, but I am not sure if the problem is being caused by my WatchService, or the File, or the FileReader, so I wanted to include as much information as possible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint at `new FileReader(theFile);` and when it hits go to the directory where it should be there and check if its really there?

Comment: Why do you use `File` when you use `Path`?? It's like using an ox cart when you have a car

Comment: I am certain that the file exists in that directory because as part of my testing I am physically dropping files into the directory in order to proc WatchService to create a WatchEvent. But I have also just now added a breakpoint at that line of code, and the file still exists in the directory before the line of code is executed.

And to answer your question, I use `File` instead of `Path` because as far as I can see, there is no constructor for `FileReader` that takes a `Path` argument. Only `String`, `File`, and `FileDescriptor`.

Comment: You can add a `if( thefile.exists() )` before  `new FileReader (...)` and see if it resolves to true, and also you may try `new FileReader( theFile.getAbsoluteFile() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the file exists because my WatchService detected the file being created and provided the file's path with trigger.context().

No it didn't.

You failed to query for the *type* of the event. The JDK provides [these standard types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html), yet you only check whether there's an overflow.

You have to check whether the event received is actually either a modification or a creation (ie, `StandardWatchEventKind.EVENT_{CREATE,MODIFY}`).

What is more, [don't use `File`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). Use `Path` all the way.

Once you have ensured that the event is a creation or modification, then open an `InputStream` or a `Reader` to the file using either [`Files.newInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) or [`Files.newBufferedReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-). If, using this, you still get an exception, at least it will be a much more meaningful one than `FileNotFoundException` (read the link I posted above...).

Comment: Thank you for the response. My understanding of what I have done with WatchService is that with this line `WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);` my WatchService only watches for  `CREATE` and `OVERFLOW`. What's more is that I have added a debug statement directly after `WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();` to `println` the kind, and in every one of my tests, it has been a `CREATE`.

Thank you for the advice on `Path` vs `File`. I am now using `Files.newBufferedReader(Path)` instead of `new FileReader(theFile)`, and I am getting a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`.

Comment: Can you please print the values of "dir" and "theFile" in your program. When I ran your code. i was getting different values for both of them. After debug i changed the Path dir value to what I got for theFile and it works. Also as fge suggested I changed entry_create to StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.

Comment: Oh wow, that's amazing, now I feel stupid. You're right, the value of dir and the path of theFile do not match.

For some reason the toAbsolutePath() is not actually giving the file the correct path, it's putting it in the wrong folder. And I assumed it was working properly.

Thank you for pointing out the obvious for me :)